# React CORS error occurs when integrating with graphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, graphql, apollo-client

Now I'm doing an authentication project to learn how to integrate with the FE and GraphQL to store the refresh token inside the cookies and use the access token to get the information. Unfortunately I was unable to store the refresh token after I clicked the login button and the cors error even i'm following all the details and steps from the official website. Thank you everyone for being attention on it

Server Code

```
async function startApolloServer() {
  const app = express();
  app.use(cors({
    origin:'*', 
    credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
  }))
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

  app.use(cookiesParser());

  app.post("/refresh_token", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log(req.cookies);

    const token = req.cookies.jid;

    if (!token) {
      return res.send({ status: false, accessToken: "" });
    }

    let payload: any = null;

    try {
      payload = verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY as string);
    } catch (error) {
      return res.send({ status: false, accessToken: "" });
    }

    // token is valid, find user and send back accessToken

    const user: any = await AppDataSource.manager.getRepository(User).findOne({
      where: {
        id: payload.userId,
      },
    });

    if (!user) {
      return res.send({ status: false, accessToken: "" });
    }

    if (user.tokenVersion !== payload.tokenVersion) {
      return res.send({ status: false, accessToken: "" });
    }

    sendRefreshToken(res, createRefreshToken(user));

    return res.send({ status: true, accessToken: createAccessToken(user) });
  });

  const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [UserQuery, UserMutation],
  });
  await AppDataSource.initialize();

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({ req, res }) => {
      return { req, res };
    },
    csrfPrevention: true,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
  });

  await server.start();

  server.applyMiddleware({ app });
  await new Promise<void>((resolve) =>
    httpServer.listen({ port: 4000 }, resolve)
  );
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
}
```

Frontend Code

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  credentials:'include'
});
```

Error

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxj2F.jpg)

Comment: read the last line of the error. you can't give '*' value as origin in serverside when you send credentials value as 'include' from the client

Comment: Hi @Vimal any suggestion or solution about it, i'm tried everything still unable to solve it yet, ty

Comment: Even i change the origin to http://localhost:3000 it still give me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Remove * and use

```
app.use(cors())
```

If you want to allow to access backend can be accessed from anywhere. Or can use

```
 var corsOptions = {
     origin: 'http://example.com',
 }
```

If you allow any specific domain. For more options see the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).